# ortools solvers GLOP, PDLP instantly writes that the model is infeasible

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, or-tools

I have a model for solving an optimization transport problem, it contains from 5000 to 50000 variables and 1000-7000 restrictions (depending on the dataset), and I tried to run the model on the GLOP solver both with and without restrictions (that is, it is feasible in any case), but I always get the message
`WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR E0000 00:00:1710666470.315259 24996 linear_solver.cc:2024] No solution exists. MPSolverInterface::result_status_ = MPSOLVER_INFEASIBLE`,
I tried to run the model from the example from the ortools documentation and it gave a normal solution, does anyone know what the problem is?

I tried to find a solution to this problem and came across solution tolerance, I tried changing this parameter (1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-1, 1, 100, 1000) - it had no effect
Also, if the problem is in the solver, could you recommend a non-commercial solver to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide some example code of what you are trying to accomplish? Without such context it is hard to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To prevent the solver from returning "infeasible," it can be a good idea to make the model "elastic." Basically, we add extra capacity at a high cost. The solution of this model can show where we needed to add capacity to make the model feasible. That will show where there are bottlenecks or possibly data errors.